# How to download a sub directory on git.gnome.org?

Tags: git, gtk3

I want to tweak the Adwaita gtk3 theme a bit, and I found it [here](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/theme/Adwaita).

There are two many files to download, and I had no luck using neither `git clone https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/theme/Adwaita` nor `svn export https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/theme/Adwaita`

I'm sure that there is a way to download this dir, as I saw a guy using Adwaita theme as a base: [Arc-theme](https://github.com/horst3180/Arc-theme/tree/master/common/gtk-3.0)

So any of you know how to download a git.gnome.org sub dir? Thank you very much for checking my issue out!

Edit 1: Answer provided by don_crissti can do the job well (I wanted to comment a thank to his post but got advised not to do that), however, if you can't install `subversion`, e.g. don't have root access, you can download gtk+3 source package [here (at **Download**)](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+). It's only 10 MiB (as of ver 3.16.5).

Comment: You're right. The source package was such an obvious choice that I didn't even bother to mention it... I thought that for some reason you wanted the code from git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it with `svn` from [https:/github.com/GNOME](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk) (svn checkout URL is available on the right side of the page). So, to get just the `Adwaita` sub-directory simply run:

```
svn checkout https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/trunk/gtk/theme/Adwaita
```